# Using jQuery Bootgrid without Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-bootgrid

I have found this plugin to be easy-to-use with Bootstrap, having a lot of functions as well.
In my latest project, I am no longer using Bootstrap, but would like still like to use jQuery Bootgrid.

This should be possible as per [the GitHub page](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-bootgrid) (Getting strarted), but I'm not getting it to work.
Am I supposed to look at the classes it uses and implement my own CSS or can I use it more independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DatBassie:

[jQuery Bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/) is designed to work with [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). Responsiveness is the major reason.

If you are looking for a non-responsive solution, you can try different options like https://www.datatables.net (there is a responsive feature now if you like).

Everything depends on what you are looking for. You can use Bootgrid without using all Bootstrap classes, but some functionalities and look can be lost if you do it..

Comment: I thought so, thanks! I'm looking for something that allows me to edit the data, inline if possible, but that is a paid feature for DataTables, that's why I didn't use that.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that the Editor plugin is paid: https://editor.datatables.net/purchase/

Comment: Everything is possible, somebody has already modified the in-line-editing code for it: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-in-line-editing/ . More information here: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/10119/in-line-editing-php-backend-full-working-version

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that.